# pandas repeat ids based on matching column value and index

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multi-index

I have two dataframes like as below

```
row_id,var_name,score
1,revenue,10
1,cnt_days,5
1,age,15
2,revenue,11
2,cnt_days,3
2,age,25

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

unique_key,status,country,marital_status     
 123,passed,UK,Single
 456,failed,USA,Married
 789,passed,KOREA,Single

df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Match `df1` and `df2` based on `df1['row_id']` and `df2.index`

b) For matching records, attach `unique_key` to `df1`

So, I tried the below

```
pd.concat([df1, df2[['unique_key']].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

but the above doesn't work for repeating row_ids. It only matches for first occurrence of row_ids.

How can I do this for repeat occurrence of row_ids in big data dataframe?

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because match by indices in `df2` is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` - `df2['unique_key']`:

```
df1['unique_key'] = df1['row_id'].map(df2['unique_key'])
print (df1)
   row_id  var_name  score  unique_key
0       1   revenue     10         456
1       1  cnt_days      5         456
2       1       age     15         456
3       2   revenue     11         789
4       2  cnt_days      3         789
5       2       age     25         789
```

Or left join with only column `unique_key` with parameters `left_on` and `right_index`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2['unique_key'], left_on='row_id', right_index=True, how='left')
print (df)
   row_id  var_name  score  unique_key
0       1   revenue     10         456
1       1  cnt_days      5         456
2       1       age     15         456
3       2   revenue     11         789
4       2  cnt_days      3         789
5       2       age     25         789
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
df1['unique_key'] = df1.merge(df2, right_index=True, left_on='row_id')['unique_key']
```

```
print(df1)

   row_id  var_name  score  unique_key
0       1   revenue     10         456
1       1  cnt_days      5         456
2       1       age     15         456
3       2   revenue     11         789
4       2  cnt_days      3         789
5       2       age     25         789
```